# How to send text message to individual user in MS Teams using c# and incoming web hooks

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

Can anybody knows how to send the text message to **individual user** in Microsoft Teams using incoming hooks in c#.

Thanks in advance.

I can able to send the text messages in teams channel and not in individual users chat.

Below is my code -

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://example.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/4dee1c26-036c-4bd2-af75-eb1abd901d18@3c69a296-d747-4ef3-9cc5-e94ee78db030/IncomingWebhook/87557542b42d8d3b04453c4a606f2b92/b852b3d0-84b6-4d98-a547-ae5f53452235"))
                        {
                        var random = "Current Date & Time - " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                            request.Content = new StringContent("{'text':'Test Entry with "+ random + "'}");
                            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

                            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: In documentation they specify a channel for webhook. They normally create chat (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)  and after that send message (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) . You using webhook actually maybe you should use send message service.

Comment: @firatt_ do you have any example or code for sending message to 1 user from bot account like we create in webhooks

Answer (score 1):

### We can achieve above functionality using Graph API

```
    static string Token = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IldyLU1GQW96QXhZS3p3VWdtaE5vQROW5OUjdiUm9meG1lWm9YcWJIWkdldyJ9.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.nGk1MiAkIxSDHdhxVI1Fi8tiMWQ1cwpG-ar0cx7h19EsR70WzjkPX8sWQuByZ4m70mkpuELLTzzV8x2A1stX7eYx7JA7BP8sNb8bNyTaBSO-M-EJD1YEMiq-xqqOyN-rSKiMF6gzK50x5LhfvdhV-TVmIzS-cx5ijiIqwUbdHep5EFFkT38gDLeuJ-Ihe_WK1iVSqn6lLNHXK1okOL2SSf0xDGpg08rEuneFTzL5nXk-KyKM0HwT4DVlZCLDgmuXGqjjgbbtk_HKEOYMw2Mj1M-np_SEojpPu5K0NzeuXd_qjZxFt9sL2Xvm9vRZzBqGtb47TwksbwrBZl_6XO0qgw";

public static void SendMessage()
{
    string msg = "Current Date & Time - " + DateTime.Now.ToString();


    /* Pass the sender and receiver email id in below method. Email Id should be microsoft account like outlook/office365 */

    string result1 = GetChatID("sender@outlook.com", "receiver@outlook.com");

    dynamic lstResult1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result1);

    /* Pass the chat id in below method received from above method. */

    string result2 = SendMessageInChat(Convert.ToString(lstResult1["id"]), msg);
}

public static string GetChatID(string SenderID, string ReceiverID)
{
    string Response = "";
    string JSONBody = "";

    try
    {
        string MSTeams_GetChatIDURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats";

        /* For Individual User - set \"chatType\": \"oneOnOne\"
           And For Group - set \"chatType\": \"group\" and add one more optional parameter \"topic\": \"group name\"
           Change in JSON Body.
        */
        
        JSONBody = "{\"chatType\": \"oneOnOne\",\"members\": [{\"@odata.type\": \"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember\",\"roles\": [\"owner\"],\"user@odata.bind\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('" + SenderID.ToString().Trim() + "')\"},{\"@odata.type\": \"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember\",\"roles\": [\"owner\"],\"user@odata.bind\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('" + ReceiverID.ToString().Trim() + "')\"}]}";
        
        var client = new RestClient(MSTeams_GetChatIDURL);
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", Token);

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", JSONBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Response = response.Content;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    
    return Response;
}

public static string SendMessageInChat(string ChatID, string Message)
{
    string Response = "";
    string JSONBody = "";

    try
    {
        string MSTeams_SendMessageURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/{ChatID}/messages";

        JSONBody = "{\"body\": {\"contentType\": \"html\",\"content\": \"<div><div><div><span>"+ Message.ToString() + "<img height='250' src='https://picsum.photos/200/300' width='176.2295081967213' style='vertical-align:bottom; width:176px; height:250px'></span></div></div></div>\"}}";

        var client = new RestClient(MSTeams_SendMessageURL.ToString().Replace("{ChatID}",ChatID));
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        request.AddHeader("Authorization", Token);

        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("application/json", JSONBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Response = response.Content;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    
    return Response;
}
```

**Get the token from below image link -** [image]

**And also below permissions are needed -**
[image]
[image]